# How to incorporate wso2 esb fix?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have installed DSS feature on ESB. While deploying DSS artifact, I came across error similar to one below

WARN - DefaultAppDeployer Can't deploy artifact : EmployeeDataService of type : service/dataservice. Required features are not installed in the system

The wso2 jira indicates that the issue has been resolved
https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15657

How do I incorporate this fix in my wso2 esb 4.9 installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get relevant patches for that fixes and apply to your version. As most of patches are provided upon customer requests, it is better to use release versions which are having those fixes.

In ESB 5.0.0, all fixes are attached and it may be release within this month (July, 2016).