# ESB + DSS feature. DefaultAppDeployer Can't deploy artifact. How to apply available fix

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have installed DSS feature on ESB, but when i try to deploy DSS artifacts i get the following error:

WARN - DefaultAppDeployer Can't deploy artifact : EmployeeDataService of type : service/dataservice. Required features are not installed in the system

I saw this answer [How to incorporate wso2 esb fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38106814/how-to-incorporate-wso2-esb-fix) but i am constrained to use ESB 4.9.x.

how can i apply the fix available at this link? (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/CARBON-15657) Do i need to re-compile the whole product?

does any of these patches (http://wso2.com/security-patch-releases/) include the fix?

**UPDATE**

I tested the following builds:

- ESB490-RC4-Final/
- 4.10.0-Releases/4.10.0-M2/

available at svn.wso2.org

ESB490-RC4-Final suffer the same problem;
4.10.0-M2 it show another problem: [issue in installing DSS feature on wso2 ESB 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643903/issue-in-installing-dss-feature-on-wso2-esb-5-0) (actually on a different library)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this fix is not included in any security patch.

But you dont have to recompile and build the whole product. You can just patch the carbon-kernel component. For that

1. Checkout the source at the [this](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/tree/v4.4.2) point or checkout carbon-kernel and do the change locally.
2. Build carbon-kernel product.
3. Locate to built WSO2 Carbon - Application Deployer jar (core/org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer/target/org.wso2.carbon.application.deployer.jar).
4. follow [this guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon420/Creating+a+Carbon+Kernel+Patch#CreatingaCarbonKernelPatch-Creatingapatch) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26601122/1812666) to create and install your own patch using the above jar.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed the instrictions but still get the same error: WARN - DefaultAppDeployer Can't deploy artifact : EmployeeDataService of type : service/dataservice. Required features are not installed in the system

Comment: I used WUM (http://wso2.com/update) to create an updated version of ESB:

details:

Product Name:           wso2esb
Product Version:        4.9.0
Kernel Version:         4.4.1
Last Updated Time:      2016-09-30T17:25:09+02:00
Installed Updates:      96.

but still the same error persist:

DefaultAppDeployer Can't deploy artifact : EmployeeDataService of type : service/dataservice. Required features are not installed in the system